# Can't push an image to Openshift (unauthorized: authentication required)

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-online

I'm new to Openshift and Docker.

I created a new project on Openshift, and a new image stream as well so I can push a docker image I created to the docker repository inside my Openshift project.

After login in with docker to the registry as explained in the Openshift documentation, and getting a `Login succeded` message, I went ahead to tag my image, and push it to the image stream, only to get a message stating `Unauthorized: authentication required`.

```
sudo docker login -u `oc whoami` -p `oc whoami -t` registry.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com
```

`sudo docker tag test:latest registry.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com/rolabot/test`

`sudo docker push registry.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com/rolabot/test`

This last command returns

```
3ea53db680fc: Pushing [==================================================>]  12.8 kB
54f43adb4662: Pushing 1.536 kB
49907af65b0a: Pushing [==================================================>] 3.072 kB
4589f96366e6: Pushing [==================================================>] 5.632 kB
b97229212d30: Pushing 14.85 kB
cd181336f142: Waiting 
0f5ff0cf6a1c: Waiting 
unauthorized: authentication required
```

Comment: Can you update your questions with the exact commands you used?

Comment: Sure, give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: @DerekBrown Edit posted.

Comment: 1) what is the output of `oc whoami`? 2) Do you have an OpenShift project called `rolabot`?

Comment: @DerekBrown 1) My username. `oc whoami -t` returns my auth token. 2) Yes.

Comment: I think the problem is that the image name is invalid.  Make sure it is of the format `${REGISTRY}/${PROJECT}/${IMAGE_NAME}:{IMAGE_VERSION}`.  Otherwise docker has no way of disambiguating `test` images posted by other users.

Comment: @DerekBrown That would be a no. Even adding latest to the tag and the push request returns the same error.

Comment: does your account have admin privileges over the project?

Comment: @DerekBrown I created the project myself, so I'd suppose this is the case, however, I don't know how to check.

Comment: that would be a yes.

Comment: have you tried rebuilding the image locally and pushing the updated build?  I know it sounds stupid, but it seems like this resolves the issue sometimes (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3009161)

Comment: @DerekBrown Yes. The image, in fact, was built locally to start with, but I've rebuilt it a couple of times just in case it had something to do, to no avail.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what docker version are you running locally?

Comment: @DerekBrown `$ docker -v 
Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802`

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems like this is an issue with the upstream Docker Registry cache in Origin.  This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/minishift/minishift/issues/817) in `minishift`, but the remedies they have found are not possible (as you don't have the necessary permissions) on Openshift Online.  I would open a new support ticket with Red Hat, so that they can take a look.

Comment: I hope this is not the case. I'll see if i can ask for support tomorrow, even though I'm a free member, so I don't know how that'll go. I'll make sure to mark this answer as accepted if it comes to that, but I'll wait for more answer in the meanwhile. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems you can also maybe open an issue on GitHub Issues.  They are responsive there as well.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems you can try deploying via hub.docker.com as a workaround. It is the main repo and it is free for public repositories. It can automatically do a docker build from GitHub or BitBucket repo. If you don't want it to build your image you can simply push from local by tagging as "username/blah:tag" then push and as long as the "username" matches your account it works. See the first section of this doc for example of pushing a local build https://github.com/simbo1905/cu-final-mssql/blob/master/meetup.md#checkout-and-build-the-code-using-net-core-aka-dotnet

Comment: @simbo1905 While this workaround is far from optimal, it works! I can now use the image in an app, though I'm having problems with it being deployed, but that has nothing to do with this question. If you are willing to post an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems your welcome. My answer isn't really a fix so please just vote up my comments and I will get a point or two.